# How to skip already processed files

Tags: java

I have an application that iterates through a folder full of files and extracts text from them. I want the application to log files it has processed and then when the programme is re-run, to skip those files in the same folder it has already extracted text from. At the moment I am able to log the files that have been processed, but when I re-run the programme the files are re-processed which slows everything down. What's wrong with below and is there a more efficient way?

```
public class Iterator {
    static HashSet<String> myFiles = new HashSet<String>();
    public static Preferences prefs;
    static String filename= "/Files/FilesLogged.txt";
    static String folderName;
    static Path p;
    public Iterator() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, SQLException, ParseException, URISyntaxException, BackingStoreException {       
        Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TBB_SQLBuilder.class);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(filename)),2048);
        String line = null;
        //Reading the files from the logger so they can be avoided
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            myFiles.add(line);
        }


            //This iterates through each of the files in the specified folder and copies them to a log. 
            //It also checks to see if that file has been read already so that it isn't re-inputted into the database if run again               
            //Loop through the ArrayList with the full path names of each folder in the outer loop

            String[] keys = userPrefs.keys();
            for (String folderName : keys) {
                //Extract the folder name from the Prefs and iterate through
                if(userPrefs.get(folderName, null)!=null){
                        loopthrough(userPrefs.get(folderName, null));   
                }
            }   
            reader.close();
}               





public static void loopthrough(String folderName) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, SQLException, ParseException, URISyntaxException{

        File dir = new File(folderName);
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();        
            if (directoryListing != null) {
                for (File child : directoryListing) {

                        if(!myFiles.contains(child.getName())){
                        Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TBB_SQLBuilder.class);
                        FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(userPrefs.get("PathForLogger", null),true);

                                     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw,2048);
                                     bw.write(child.getName().toString().trim());
                                     bw.newLine();
                                     bw.flush();
                                     bw.close();
                                     fw.close();

                                                               }
                                                   }
                                             }
      }

 }
```

Comment: Try to debug and examine the contents of `myFiles`, maybe there is some differences in the file names in the set and in file system.

Comment: independent from your issue: there is a class `java.util.Iterator` in the Java standard library. I avoid naming my classes like standard classes

Answer (score 1):

Typically when processing files, you do the following:
When you start processing, the first thing you do is move the file to ..inprocess or something similar or  move it to an inprocess directory.
When you finish processing you change the name to ..done or something similar or  move it to a done directory.
That way when you look for files to process, you can avoid the inprocess and done ones. It also makes it easy to see what needs reprocessing

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two different files the programm read and writes.

1. The file for reading:

   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(filename)),2048);
2. The file for writing:

   Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TBB_SQLBuilder.class);

   FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(userPrefs.get("PathForLogger", null),true);

Of course the programm must not use different files.

Answer (score 0):

create a test environment with 20 files or less to examine.

Change your code:

```java
    String line = null;
    //Reading the files from the logger so they can be avoided
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        myFiles.add(line);
        System.out.println("already processed: "+line);
    }
```

```java
        for (File child : directoryListing)
        {
            String fileToCheck = child.getName();
            System.out.println("file to process: "+fileToCheck);
            if (!myFiles.contains(fileToCheck))
            {
                Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TBB_SQLBuilder.class);
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(userPrefs.get("PathForLogger", null), true);

                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw, 2048);
                bw.write(fileToCheck.trim());
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                bw.close();
                fw.close();
            }
        }
```

Compare the filenames "already processed" and "file to check".

Or use a debugger.